# How to plot graph using two lists where first list is normal list and second list contains list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot graph using two lists x and y where-

```
x=['18ww25', '18ww27', '18ww28', '18ww28.1', '18ww29', '18ww29.1', '18ww29.2']

y=[['27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%'], ['18%', '18%', '20%', '23%', '30%', '30%', '30%'], ['24%', '25%', '28%', '32%', '39%', '39%', '43%'], ['43%', '43%', '44%', '44%', '43%', '45%', '45%'], ['0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%'], ['14%', '14%', '16%', '16%', '16%', '17%', '17%'], ['14%', '14%', '14%', '14%', '14%', '14%', '14%'], ['0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%'], ['8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%']]
```

I have to plot graph with each `x` and `y` pair . I have to plot list `x` with every list of `y` in the same graph, such as: `(x,y1)` `(x,y2)` ... `(x,y9)` (as total 9 elements are there in `y`).

The code that I am using right now is:

```
 plt.xlabel("X-axis")
    plt.ylabel("Y-axis")
    plt.title("A test graph")
    for i in range(len(y)):
        plt.plot(x,[pt[i] for pt in y],label = 'id %s'%i)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

but this code is showing error as

```
x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (7,) and (9,)
```

How can I plot this?

Comment: x has 7 elements while y has 9 elements hence the issue exists. What will be the x coordinates for the last 2 y elements?

Comment: `plt.plot(x,y[i],label = 'id %s'%i)` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to plot

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    plt.plot(x, y[i], label = 'id %s'%i)
```

However you would probably change the y values to numbers first, else they would not be to scale. In total that may look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=['18ww25', '18ww27', '18ww28', '18ww28.1', '18ww29', '18ww29.1', '18ww29.2']
y=[['27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%'], 
   ['18%', '18%', '20%', '23%', '30%', '30%', '30%'], 
   ['24%', '25%', '28%', '32%', '39%', '39%', '43%'], 
   ['43%', '43%', '44%', '44%', '43%', '45%', '45%'], 
   ['0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%'], 
   ['14%', '14%', '16%', '16%', '16%', '17%', '17%'], 
   ['14%', '14%', '14%', '14%', '14%', '14%', '14%'], 
   ['0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0%'], 
   ['8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%', '8%']]

z = [list(map(lambda s: float(s.split("%")[0]),yi)) for yi in y]

plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis [%]")
plt.title("A test graph")
for i in range(len(z)):
    plt.plot(x,z[i],label = 'id %s'%i)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The pattern 'for i in range(len(x))' should imo be replaced by 'for i, v in enumerate(x)'

Comment: thank you for your valuable input.It is working fine.can you please tell me what to include in the  code such that for every plot of (x,z[i]) markers are used that represent the z[i] values.Like for "id 0 " line markers are used representing z[i] values-@ImportanceOfBeingErnes

Comment: you mean `marker="s"`? Or do you want a different marker for each line?

Comment: Thank you for your response .what i meant is like  if we are plotting line for (['18ww25', '18ww27', '18ww28', '18ww28.1', '18ww29', '18ww29.1', '18ww29.2']   and  ['27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%', '27%'] )  then for every point in the plotted line say for ('18ww25' , '27%')  point the marker should be 27 (the y cordinate of each point ) - @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: can you please help me with that because its really important part of the plot-@ImportanceOfBeingErnest